# Error when make a build of the game in Uneral Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

When I try to make a build, I'm getting error

*Cannot open include file: 'Actions/PawnAction.h': No such file or directory*

[image]

But I have this file in Visual Studio

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `AIModule` in your module dependencies.

Source: [JamieDale from UE4 Q&A site](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/81420/build-fails-for-aicontroller.html#):

> Right, so if your game was called "MyGame", then you'd have a file called "MyGame.Build.cs" inside the "Source\MyGame" folder.
>
> This file tells the UnrealBuildTool (UBT) what to do when building your game.
>
> In there you should see an array for PrivateDependencyModuleNames and/or PublicDependencyModuleNames - this tells UBT which modules need to be linked when building your game, so you'll need to add "AIModule" to one of those.